# PHP - Fetching xml values with looping over n unbounded element

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xmlreader

I'm fetching some xml and convert it to csv similar to below. Some of the records have additional n (unbounded) elements ("EntityEvents"). How can I fetch them as well and write them into a second (mm) csv file?

This is my structure:

XML File:

```
<abc:ABCData xmlns:abc="http://www.abc-example.com" xmlns:xyz="http:/www.xyz-example.com">
<abc:ABCRecords>
  <abc:ABCRecord>
    <abc:ABC>5EXZX4LPK</abc:ABC>
    <abc:Entity>
      <abc:Name>Bornheim</abc:Name>
      <abc:EntityEvents>
        <abc:EntityEvent>
          <abc:EntityEventType>TypeA</abc:EntityEventType>
          <abc:EntityEventName>EventA</abc:EntityEventName> 
        </abc:EntityEvent>
      </abc:EntityEvents>    
    </abc:Entity>
  </abc:ABCRecord>
  <abc:ABCRecord>
    <abc:ABC>5967007LI</abc:ABC>
    <abc:Entity>
      <abc:Name>MOON BANK</abc:Name>
      <abc:EntityEvents>
        <abc:EntityEvent>
          <abc:EntityEventType>TypeB</abc:EntityEventType>
          <abc:EntityEventName>EventB</abc:EntityEventName>         
        </abc:EntityEvent>
        <abc:EntityEvent>
          <abc:EntityEventType>TypeC</abc:EntityEventType>
          <abc:EntityEventName>EventC</abc:EntityEventName>         
        </abc:EntityEvent>
      </abc:EntityEvents>                   
    </abc:Entity>
  </abc:ABCRecord>
  <abc:ABCRecord>
    <abc:ABC>2792340TZ</abc:ABC>
    <abc:Entity>
      <abc:Name>SUN BANK</abc:Name>
      <abc:EntityEvents>
        <abc:EntityEvent>
          <abc:EntityEventType>TypeD</abc:EntityEventType>
          <abc:EntityEventName>EventD</abc:EntityEventName>         
        </abc:EntityEvent>
        <abc:EntityEvent>
          <abc:EntityEventType>TypeF</abc:EntityEventType>
          <abc:EntityEventName>EventF</abc:EntityEventName>         
        </abc:EntityEvent>
        <abc:EntityEvent>
          <abc:EntityEventType>TypeG</abc:EntityEventType>
          <abc:EntityEventName>EventG</abc:EntityEventName>         
        </abc:EntityEvent>
      </abc:EntityEvents>                   
    </abc:Entity>
  </abc:ABCRecord>   
</abc:ABCRecords>
</abc:ABCData>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('php://stdin');

$output = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
fputcsv($output, ['id', 'name']);

$xmlns = [
  'abc' => 'http://www.abc-example.com'
];

$dom   = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xmlns as $prefix => $namespaceURI) {
  $xpath->registerNamespace($prefix, $namespaceURI);
}

while (
  $reader->read() && 
  (
    $reader->localName !== 'ABCRecord' || 
    $reader->namespaceURI !== $xmlns['abc']
  )
) {
  continue;
}

while ($reader->localName === 'ABCRecord') {
  if ($reader->namespaceURI === 'http://www.abc-example.com') {
    $node = $reader->expand($dom);
    fputcsv(
      $output, 
      [
        $xpath->evaluate('string(abc:ABC)', $node),
        $xpath->evaluate('string(abc:Entity/abc:Name)', $node)
      ]
    );
  }

  $reader->next('ABCRecord');
}
```

Output 1 (CSV):

```
5EXZX4LPK,Bornheim
5967007LI,"MOON BANK"
2792340TZ,"SUN BANK"
```

Desired Output 2 (CSV):

```
5EXZX4LPK,TypeA,EventA
5967007LI,TypeB,EventB
5967007LI,TypeC,EventC
2792340TZ,TypeD,EventD
2792340TZ,TypeE,EventE
2792340TZ,TypeF,EventF
```

How can I accomplish this? I thought of writing them into a separate file but I'm open how to accomplish this. I'm also open to do it in two steps, meaning in a separate php file.

Comment: You have several closing `</abc:Event>` nodes which are never opened; is that a typo?

Comment: @JackFleeting Yes this was a typo, sorry! Updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a secondary file handle. Then after expanding the node into DOM, use an expression to fetch the events and write them to the second file.

```php
//...
$node = $reader->expand($dom);
// store the identifier
$identifier = $xpath->evaluate('string(abc:ABC)', $node);
fputcsv(
  $output, 
  [
    $identifier,
    $xpath->evaluate('string(abc:Entity/abc:Name)', $node)
  ]
);
// iterate the EntityEvent elements
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('abc:Entity/abc:EntityEvents/abc:EntityEvent', $node) as $event) {
  fputcsv(
    $detailOutput, 
    [
      $identifier,
      $xpath->evaluate('string(abc:EntityEventType)', $event),
      $xpath->evaluate('string(abc:EntityEventName)', $event)
    ]
  ); 
}
//...
```

The code in you question implements the first node list iteration in XMLReader to avoid loading the whole document into memory. After the `XMLReader::expand()` you got a DOM node.

Reading DOM with Xpath is always one of two. A basic location path returns a node list (example: `ancestor/parent/child`). The result will always be a list, if the the expression does not match it will be an empty list. Xpath expressions can get a lot more complex - they allow for conditions, nesting and alternatives.

If you need a single value you can cast the location path using an Xpath function (example: `string(ancestor/parent/child)`). Functions like `string()` or `number()` will cast the first value from the node list or return a default value. `string()` will return an empty string if the expression itself did not match. Other methods or the use of an operator can result in a type cast as well (example: `count(ancestor/parent/child) > 0`).

However if you can read the values from the current node using DOM methods/properties I would suggest doing so. The Xpath is unnecessary overhead in this cases.

```php
// fetch and iterate nodes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression, $contextNode) as $childNode) {
  var_dump(
    // reading an attribute 
    $childNode->getAttribute('attribute-one'),
    // the node name (without the namespace prefix)
    $childNode->localName,
    // using Xpath for nested data
    $xpath->evaluate('string(child)', $childNode)
  );
}
```

Comment: Already thanks for the help. I did a small typo though, sorry ... what if there are multiple values within an 'EntityEvent' element?! I updated the question accordingly. Thanks again for the support

Comment: You use the same approach as with the `abc:Name` element. With DOM+Xpath it always one of two: 1) fetching and iterating a node list 2) fetch a single value by using a cast. If you need values from the current node use the DOM methods/properties (getAttribute()/textContent). No need for Xpath in this case.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm almost there. The ->getAttribute() and ->evaluate() way works ... but with the $event->EntityEventType and $event->EntityEventName I'm still struggeling. Can you be a bit more specific or add an example in your first part of your answer (with EventType and EventName & localName)?

Comment: `$event->EntityEventType` would be SimpleXML, it does not work with DOM objects. You need to use DOMXpath::evaluate(), but check the second argument. This is the context node for the Xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it somewhat differently:

```
$targets = $xpath->query("//abc:ABCRecord");
foreach ($targets as $target) {
  $id = $xpath->query('.//abc:ABC', $target)[0]->nodeValue;
  $events = $xpath->query('.//abc:EntityEvent', $target);
  foreach ($events as $event) {
    $type = $xpath->query('.//abc:EntityEventType', $event)[0]->nodeValue;
    $name = $xpath->query('.//abc:EntityEventName', $event)[0]->nodeValue;
    fputcsv(
      $output,
      [
        $id,
        $type,
        $name
      ]
    );
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a single XPath expression and tag names to fill arrays. Building a csv object should be trivial.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$csv1 = [];
$csv2 = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("(//abc:ABCRecord/abc:ABC | //abc:Entity/abc:Name) | (//abc:ABCRecord/abc:ABC | //abc:ABCRecord//abc:EntityEvent)") as $ele) {
  if($ele -> localName == 'ABC'){
    $n = $ele->nodeValue;
  }
  if($ele -> localName == 'Name'){
    $csv1[] = $n . ','. $ele -> nodeValue;
  }else if($ele -> localName == 'EntityEvent'){
    $csv2[] = $n . ','. $ele -> nodeValue;
  }
}
var_dump($csv1);
var_dump($csv2);
```

Result

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "5EXZX4LPK,Bornheim"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "5967007LI,MOON BANK"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "2792340TZ,SUN BANK"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "5EXZX4LPK,EventA"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "5967007LI,EventB"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "5967007LI,EventC"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "2792340TZ,EventD"
  [4]=>
  string(16) "2792340TZ,EventF"
  [5]=>
  string(16) "2792340TZ,EventG"
}
```